# does exportfs -r interrupts the existing nfs?

Tags: linux, nfs

I'm trying to export a new nfs volume while keeping other ones running. my concern is if somehow, there is a risk for the processes that are writing in the others nfs volumes.
am using `/etc/exportfs` and `exportfs -r`.